# MySQL update automatically a column after update

Tags: mysql, triggers, sql-update

As the title says, I have a table with a column named **last_update** of type **DATE**. I want to make a **trigger** that set it to **CURDATE()** every time I update a row(set it for this particular row). I tried this:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_customer_update before update on customer for each row
begin
update customer set last_update = CURDATE() where id = old.id;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

but a get an error

> can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already
>   used by statement

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be easier to change the column definition to

```
last_update timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

If you really want to do it in a trigger (refer to the current record with `NEW`):

Replace

```
update customer set last_update = CURDATE() where id = old.id;
```

with

```
set NEW.last_update = CURDATE();
```

Comment: I get the same error. I want to use Date because I connect my DB to a Java project where the variable that corespond to last_update column is of type Date

Comment: But the Java  `Date` type also contains time. And I really doubt your get the same error.